# Permanent bottom margin

Tags: cursor-motions, cursor

Is it possible to keep a permanent bottom margin in the editing area, so that the cursor never touches the very bottom of the screen?

So that when the cursor goes all the way down, I can still see a few lines underneath it, and the cursor doesn't touch the status bar.

Something like `scroll_context_lines` in Sublime Text:

```
    // Set the number of context lines to show when scrolling to reveal. This
    // affects all selection changes, like selection dragging, page-up/page-down
    // and moving the caret.
    "scroll_context_lines": 6,
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
set scrolloff=6
```

It ensure that at least 6 context lines are displayed in both directions

Comment: Thanks! I have corrected the answer :-)

Comment: Thanks, it works! Sadly, there's a glitch when vim-longlines plugin is used, which is needed for editing markdown. Have already posted a bug report, https://github.com/manu-mannattil/vim-longlines/issues/3